# habilitar errores php.ini

Tags: php, wamp

No entiendo porque no logro visualizar en pantalla los errores de depuracion php.

Estoy en un entorno local **WAMP** , que contiene :

```
 apache 2.2.22

 php 5.3.13

 mysql 5.5
```

Me dirijo al **php.ini** de **php** y modifico la linea:

```
 error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
 display_errors = On
 display_startup_errors = On
```

En la ruta de **apache** tambien existe un **php.ini** el cual tengo con la misma configuración....

Alguien podrá ayudarme a ver el motivo del porque no logro visualizar los errores ?

**php.ini :**

```
                [PHP]



            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Language Options ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

            ; Enable the PHP scripting language engine under Apache.
            engine = On

            ; Enable compatibility mode with Zend Engine 1 (PHP 4.x)
            zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = Off

            ; Allow the <? tag.  Otherwise, only <?php and <script> tags are recognized.
            ; NOTE: Using short tags should be avoided when developing applications or
            ; libraries that are meant for redistribution, or deployment on PHP
            ; servers which are not under your control, because short tags may not
            ; be supported on the target server. For portable, redistributable code,
            ; be sure not to use short tags.
            short_open_tag = On

            ; Allow ASP-style <% %> tags.
            asp_tags = Off

            ; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
            precision    =  12

            ; Enforce year 2000 compliance (will cause problems with non-compliant browsers)
            y2k_compliance = On

            ; Output buffering allows you to send header lines (including cookies) even
            ; after you send body content, at the price of slowing PHP's output layer a
            ; bit.  You can enable output buffering during runtime by calling the output
            ; buffering functions.  You can also enable output buffering for all files by
            ; setting this directive to On.  If you wish to limit the size of the buffer
            ; to a certain size - you can use a maximum number of bytes instead of 'On', as
            ; a value for this directive (e.g., output_buffering=4096).
            output_buffering = Off


            zlib.output_compression = Off


            implicit_flush = Off


            unserialize_callback_func=

            ; When floats & doubles are serialized store serialize_precision significant
            ; digits after the floating point. The default value ensures that when floats
            ; are decoded with unserialize, the data will remain the same.
            serialize_precision = 100


            allow_call_time_pass_reference = On


            safe_mode = Off

            ; By default, Safe Mode does a UID compare check when
            ; opening files. If you want to relax this to a GID compare,
            ; then turn on safe_mode_gid.
            safe_mode_gid = Off

            ; When safe_mode is on, UID/GID checks are bypassed when
            ; including files from this directory and its subdirectories.
            ; (directory must also be in include_path or full path must
            ; be used when including)
            safe_mode_include_dir =

            ; When safe_mode is on, only executables located in the safe_mode_exec_dir
            ; will be allowed to be executed via the exec family of functions.
            safe_mode_exec_dir =


            safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_

            ; This directive contains a comma-delimited list of environment variables that
            ; the end user won't be able to change using putenv().  These variables will be
            ; protected even if safe_mode_allowed_env_vars is set to allow to change them.
            safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH


            disable_functions =

            ; This directive allows you to disable certain classes for security reasons.
            ; It receives a comma-delimited list of class names. This directive is
            ; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
            disable_classes =


            expose_php = On


            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Resource Limits ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

            max_execution_time = 360     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
            max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
            memory_limit = 120M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)


            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Error handling and logging ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

            ; error_reporting is a bit-field.  Or each number up to get desired error
            ; reporting level
            ; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings (doesn't include E_STRICT)
            ; E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
            ; E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
            ; E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
            ; E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
            ;                     from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
            ;                     intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
            ;                     relying on the fact it's automatically initialized to an
            ;                     empty string)
            ; E_STRICT          - run-time notices, enable to have PHP suggest changes
            ;                     to your code which will ensure the best interoperability
            ;                     and forward compatibility of your code
            ; E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
            ; E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
            ;                     initial startup
            ; E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
            ; E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
            ; E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
            ; E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
            ; E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
            ;
            ; Examples:
            ;
            ;   - Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings
            ;
            ;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
            ;
            ;   - Show all errors, except for notices
            ;
            ;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT
            ;
            ;   - Show only errors
            ;
            ;error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
            ;
            ;   - Show all errors except for notices and coding standards warnings
            ;
            ;error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
            error_reporting  =  E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR

            ; Print out errors (as a part of the output).  For production web sites,
            ; you're strongly encouraged to turn this feature off, and use error logging
            ; instead (see below).  Keeping display_errors enabled on a production web site
            ; may reveal security information to end users, such as file paths on your Web
            ; server, your database schema or other information.
            display_errors = On

            ; Even when display_errors is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup
            ; sequence are not displayed.  It's strongly recommended to keep
            ; display_startup_errors off, except for when debugging.
            display_startup_errors = On

            ; Log errors into a log file (server-specific log, stderr, or error_log (below))
            ; As stated above, you're strongly advised to use error logging in place of
            ; error displaying on production web sites.
            log_errors = Off

            ; Set maximum length of log_errors. In error_log information about the source is
            ; added. The default is 1024 and 0 allows to not apply any maximum length at all.
            log_errors_max_len = 1024

            ; Do not log repeated messages. Repeated errors must occur in same file on same
            ; line until ignore_repeated_source is set true.
            ignore_repeated_errors = On

            ; Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this setting
            ; is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from different files or
            ; sourcelines.
            ignore_repeated_source = Off

            ; If this parameter is set to Off, then memory leaks will not be shown (on
            ; stdout or in the log). This has only effect in a debug compile, and if
            ; error reporting includes E_WARNING in the allowed list
            report_memleaks = On

            ; Store the last error/warning message in $php_errormsg (boolean).
            track_errors = On




            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Data Handling ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

            variables_order = "EGPCS"

            ; Whether or not to register the EGPCS variables as global variables.  You may
            ; want to turn this off if you don't want to clutter your scripts' global scope
            ; with user data.  This makes most sense when coupled with track_vars - in which
            ; case you can access all of the GPC variables through the $HTTP_*_VARS[],
            ; variables.
            ;
            ; You should do your best to write your scripts so that they do not require
            ; register_globals to be on;  Using form variables as globals can easily lead
            ; to possible security problems, if the code is not very well thought of.
            register_globals = On

            ; Whether or not to register the old-style input arrays, HTTP_GET_VARS
            ; and friends.  If you're not using them, it's recommended to turn them off,
            ; for performance reasons.
            register_long_arrays = On

            ; This directive tells PHP whether to declare the argv&argc variables (that
            ; would contain the GET information).  If you don't use these variables, you
            ; should turn it off for increased performance.
            register_argc_argv = On

            ; When enabled, the SERVER and ENV variables are created when they're first
            ; used (Just In Time) instead of when the script starts. If these variables
            ; are not used within a script, having this directive on will result in a
            ; performance gain. The PHP directives register_globals, register_long_arrays,
            ; and register_argc_argv must be disabled for this directive to have any affect.
            auto_globals_jit = On

            ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
            post_max_size = 8M

            ; Magic quotes
            ;

            ; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
            magic_quotes_gpc = On

            ; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
            magic_quotes_runtime = Off

            ; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
            magic_quotes_sybase = Off

            ; Automatically add files before or after any PHP document.
            auto_prepend_file =
            auto_append_file =

            ; As of 4.0b4, PHP always outputs a character encoding by default in
            ; the Content-type: header.  To disable sending of the charset, simply
            ; set it to be empty.
            ;
            ; PHP's built-in default is text/html
            default_mimetype = "text/html"
            ;default_charset = "iso-8859-1"

            ; Always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variable.
            ;always_populate_raw_post_data = On


            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Paths and Directories ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


            doc_root =

            ; The directory under which PHP opens the script using /~username used only
            ; if nonempty.
            user_dir =

            ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
            extension_dir = "C:/wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext"

            ; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
            ; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
            ; disabled on them.
            enable_dl = On




            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; File Uploads ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

            ; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
            file_uploads = On

            ; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
            ; specified).
            ;upload_tmp_dir =

            ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
            upload_max_filesize = 80M


            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Fopen wrappers ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

            ; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
            allow_url_fopen = On

            ; Define the anonymous ftp password (your email address)
            ;from="john@doe.com"

            ; Define the User-Agent string
            ; user_agent="PHP"

            ; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
            default_socket_timeout = 60




            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Dynamic Extensions ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;



            extension=ace32.dll 
            extension=adsloc32.dll 
            extension=adsodbc.dll 
            extension=aicu32.dll 
            extension=axcws32.dll 
            extension=php_advantage.dll 

            ;extension=php_mbstring.dll
            ;extension=php_bz2.dll
            ;extension=php_curl.dll
            ;extension=php_dba.dll
            extension=php_dbase.dll
            ;extension=php_exif.dll
            ;extension=php_fdf.dll
            ;extension=php_filepro.dll
            extension=php_gd2.dll
            ;extension=php_gettext.dll
            ;extension=php_ifx.dll
            ;extension=php_imap.dll
            ;extension=php_interbase.dll
            ;extension=php_ldap.dll
            extension=php_mbstring.dll
            ;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
            ;extension=php_mhash.dll
            ;extension=php_mime_magic.dll
            ;extension=php_ming.dll
            extension=php_mssql.dll
            extension=php_msql.dll

            extension=php_mysql.dll
            extension=php_mysqli.dll

            ;extension=php_oci8.dll
            ;extension=php_openssl.dll
            ;extension=php_oracle.dll
            ;extension=php_pgsql.dll
            ;extension=php_shmop.dll
            ;extension=php_snmp.dll
            extension=php_sockets.dll
            ;extension=php_sqlite.dll
            extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
            ;extension=php_tidy.dll
            ;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
            ;extension=php_xsl.dll
            ;extension=php_pdo.dll
            ;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
            ;extension=php_winbinder.dll

            extension=php_sqlsrv.dll


            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ; Module Settings ;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

            [Date]
            ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions

            date.timezone="America/Santiago"

            [Syslog]
            ; Whether or not to define the various syslog variables (e.g. $LOG_PID,
            ; $LOG_CRON, etc.).  Turning it off is a good idea performance-wise.  In
            ; runtime, you can define these variables by calling define_syslog_variables().
            define_syslog_variables  = Off

            [mail function]
            ; For Win32 only.
            SMTP = localhost
            smtp_port = 25

            ; For Win32 only.
            ;sendmail_from = me@example.com

            ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
            ;sendmail_path =

            ; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
            ; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
            ; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
            ;mail.force_extra_parameters =

            [SQL]
            sql.safe_mode = Off

            [ODBC]
            ;odbc.default_db    =  Not yet implemented
            ;odbc.default_user  =  Not yet implemented
            ;odbc.default_pw    =  Not yet implemented

            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            odbc.allow_persistent = On

            ; Check that a connection is still valid before reuse.
            odbc.check_persistent = On

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            odbc.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            odbc.max_links = -1

            ; Handling of LONG fields.  Returns number of bytes to variables.  0 means
            ; passthru.
            odbc.defaultlrl = 4096

            ; Handling of binary data.  0 means passthru, 1 return as is, 2 convert to char.
            ; See the documentation on odbc_binmode and odbc_longreadlen for an explanation
            ; of uodbc.defaultlrl and uodbc.defaultbinmode
            odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

            [MySQL]
            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            mysql.allow_persistent = On

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            mysql.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            mysql.max_links = -1


            mysql.default_port =

            ; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
            ; MySQL defaults.
            mysql.default_socket =

            ; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
            mysql.default_host =

            ; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
            mysql.default_user =


            mysql.default_password =

            ; Maximum time (in secondes) for connect timeout. -1 means no limit
            mysql.connect_timeout = 180

            ; Trace mode. When trace_mode is active (=On), warnings for table/index scans and
            ; SQL-Errors will be displayed.
            mysql.trace_mode = Off

            [MySQLi]

            ; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
            mysqli.max_links = -1


            mysqli.default_port = 3306

            ; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
            ; MySQL defaults.
            mysqli.default_socket =

            ; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
            mysqli.default_host =

            ; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
            mysqli.default_user =


            mysqli.default_pw =

            ; Allow or prevent reconnect
            mysqli.reconnect = Off

            [mSQL]
            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            msql.allow_persistent = On

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            msql.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            msql.max_links = -1

            [PostgresSQL]
            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            pgsql.allow_persistent = On

            ; Detect broken persistent links always with pg_pconnect().
            ; Auto reset feature requires a little overheads.
            pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            pgsql.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            pgsql.max_links = -1

            ; Ignore PostgreSQL backends Notice message or not.
            ; Notice message logging require a little overheads.
            pgsql.ignore_notice = 0

            ; Log PostgreSQL backends Noitce message or not.
            ; Unless pgsql.ignore_notice=0, module cannot log notice message.
            pgsql.log_notice = 0

            [Sybase]
            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            sybase.allow_persistent = On

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            sybase.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            sybase.max_links = -1

            ;sybase.interface_file = "/usr/sybase/interfaces"

            ; Minimum error severity to display.
            sybase.min_error_severity = 10

            ; Minimum message severity to display.
            sybase.min_message_severity = 10

            ; Compatability mode with old versions of PHP 3.0.
            ; If on, this will cause PHP to automatically assign types to results according
            ; to their Sybase type, instead of treating them all as strings.  This
            ; compatibility mode will probably not stay around forever, so try applying
            ; whatever necessary changes to your code, and turn it off.
            sybase.compatability_mode = Off

            [Sybase-CT]
            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            sybct.allow_persistent = On

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            sybct.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            sybct.max_links = -1

            ; Minimum server message severity to display.
            sybct.min_server_severity = 10

            ; Minimum client message severity to display.
            sybct.min_client_severity = 10

            [bcmath]
            ; Number of decimal digits for all bcmath functions.
            bcmath.scale = 0

            [browscap]
            ;browscap = extra/browscap.ini

            [Informix]
            ; Default host for ifx_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
            ifx.default_host =

            ; Default user for ifx_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
            ifx.default_user =

            ; Default password for ifx_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
            ifx.default_password =

            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            ifx.allow_persistent = On

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            ifx.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            ifx.max_links = -1

            ; If on, select statements return the contents of a text blob instead of its id.
            ifx.textasvarchar = 0

            ; If on, select statements return the contents of a byte blob instead of its id.
            ifx.byteasvarchar = 0

            ; Trailing blanks are stripped from fixed-length char columns.  May help the
            ; life of Informix SE users.
            ifx.charasvarchar = 0

            ; If on, the contents of text and byte blobs are dumped to a file instead of
            ; keeping them in memory.
            ifx.blobinfile = 0

            ; NULL's are returned as empty strings, unless this is set to 1.  In that case,
            ; NULL's are returned as string 'NULL'.
            ifx.nullformat = 0

            [Session]
            ; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
            session.save_handler = files


            session.save_path = "C:/Temp"

            ; Whether to use cookies.
            session.use_cookies = 1

            ; This option enables administrators to make their users invulnerable to
            ; attacks which involve passing session ids in URLs; defaults to 0.
            ; session.use_only_cookies = 1

            ; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
            session.name = PHPSESSID

            ; Initialize session on request startup.
            session.auto_start = 0

            ; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
            session.cookie_lifetime = 0

            ; The path for which the cookie is valid.
            session.cookie_path = /

            ; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
            session.cookie_domain =

            ; Handler used to serialize data.  php is the standard serializer of PHP.
            session.serialize_handler = php



            session.gc_probability = 1
            session.gc_divisor     = 100

            ; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
            ; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
            session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440



            session.bug_compat_42 = 1
            session.bug_compat_warn = 1

            ; Check HTTP Referer to invalidate externally stored URLs containing ids.
            ; HTTP_REFERER has to contain this substring for the session to be
            ; considered as valid.
            session.referer_check =

            ; How many bytes to read from the file.
            session.entropy_length = 0

            ; Specified here to create the session id.
            session.entropy_file =

            ;session.entropy_length = 16

            ;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom

            ; Set to {nocache,private,public,} to determine HTTP caching aspects
            ; or leave this empty to avoid sending anti-caching headers.
            session.cache_limiter = nocache

            ; Document expires after n minutes.
            session.cache_expire = 180


            session.use_trans_sid = 0


            session.hash_function = 0

            ; Define how many bits are stored in each character when converting

            session.hash_bits_per_character = 4


            url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="

            [MSSQL]
            ; Allow or prevent persistent links.
            mssql.allow_persistent = On

            ; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
            mssql.max_persistent = -1

            ; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
            mssql.max_links = -1

            ; Minimum error severity to display.
            mssql.min_error_severity = 10

            ; Minimum message severity to display.
            mssql.min_message_severity = 10

            ; Compatability mode with old versions of PHP 3.0.
            mssql.compatability_mode = Off



            ; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
            ;mssql.textlimit = 4096

            ; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
            ;mssql.textsize = 4096

            ; Limits the number of records in each batch.  0 = all records in one batch.


            ; Use NT authentication when connecting to the server
            mssql.secure_connection = Off



            ; Specify client character set. 
            ; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.comf is used
            ; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
            ;mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"

            [Assertion]




            ; Eval the expression with current error_reporting().  Set to true if you want
            ; error_reporting(0) around the eval().
            ;assert.quiet_eval = 0

            [Verisign Payflow Pro]
            ; Default Payflow Pro server.
            pfpro.defaulthost = "test-payflow.verisign.com"

            ; Default port to connect to.
            pfpro.defaultport = 443

            ; Default timeout in seconds.
            pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30



            [COM]


            [mbstring]




            [gd]


            [exif]


            [Tidy]

            tidy.clean_output = Off

            [soap]
            ; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
            soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
            ; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
            soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
            ; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used 
            ; instead of original one.
            soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400

            ; Local Variables:
            ; tab-width: 4
            ; End:
```

**httpd.conf :**

```
        ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22"


        Listen 80


        LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
        LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
        LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
        LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so

        LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
        LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so

        LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
        LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
        LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so

        LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
        LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so


        LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

        LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so


        LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so

        LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so

        LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so


        LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so

        LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so

        LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so

        LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

        LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/php5apache2_2.dll"

        <IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
        <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>

        User daemon
        Group daemon

        </IfModule>
        </IfModule>


        ServerAdmin admin@localhost


        ServerName 127.0.0.1:80


        DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"


        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
        </Directory>


        <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">

            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks


            AllowOverride all


            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all

        </Directory>


        <IfModule dir_module>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
        </IfModule>


        <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
            Satisfy All
        </FilesMatch>


        ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"


        LogLevel warn

        <IfModule log_config_module>

            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

            <IfModule logio_module>

              LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
            </IfModule>


            CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" common


        </IfModule>

        <IfModule alias_module>

            ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "cgi-bin/"

        </IfModule>

        <IfModule cgid_module>

        </IfModule>

        <Directory "cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>


        DefaultType text/plain

         <IfModule mime_module>a
            TypesConfig conf/mime.types


            AddType application/x-compress .Z
            AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3


        </IfModule>


        Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf


        <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
        </IfModule>

        Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
```

Comment: Revisa bien el `php.ini`, asegurándote de que es el correcto el que estás modificando y que más adelante (en el mismo archivo) el reporte de errores no es desactivado. Luego, puedes también probar a colocar esto al inicio del script `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Si los errores se muestran entonces significa que hay alguna parte del código que los deshabilita. Debes entonces verficar el *recorrido* que hace tu código: requires, includes, instancias de clase, etc.

Comment: reiniciaste el servicio de apache después de hacer los cambios?

Comment: @Andrés si, claro, reinicio el servicio y no se aplica.

Comment: @A.Cedano existe un php.ini por php y el otro por apache. ambos los modifique de la misma forma.  anteriormente había configurado de cero y no tuve el problema, pero ahora nuevamente lo instale (misma versión) y no entiendo porque no visualizo...

Comment: @enxaneta los mismo le respondi a Andres, Si.

Comment: Prodias poner todo el documento `php.ini` y el `httpd.conf`?.

Comment: @Andrés pegue el php.ini

Comment: Es muy extraño lo que te pasa ya que en teoría todo esta bien, por el momento la unca solución que te puedo decir es que lo habilites en tu código con: `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`